# Regex not working as expcted

Tags: regex

I need help with the below regex:

```
(0 ?)([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}|(\d ?){10}
```

- The regex should match either **10** or **11 digits**
- The **first digit** should be 0
- The **second digit** should contain from **1 - 8 digits** only
- All digits **can have spaces in between** e.g. 0 1 2 7 4 3 3 3 4 4 4
- Digits can be without spaces e.g. 01274333444

The regex I created works for most of the scenarios apart from the third condition i.e. The second digit should contain from 1 - 8 digits only.
Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Your regex matches 11 or 12 digits.

Comment: There is a very cool online tool to test regex: http://regex101.com/ You might want to try it out. You can type in digits and see when they are matching. It also explains what you are selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(0\s?)([1-8]\s?)(\d\s?){8,9}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what your regex `(0 ?)([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}|(\d ?){10}` is currently doing:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It's also trying to match 11 or 12 digits instead of 10 or 11.

**What you need to do is change it one of the following ways:**

- Add a group around the OR `|` to limit it's scope:  `(0 ?)([1-8] ?){1}(?:(\d ?){8}|(\d ?){9})`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- Or preferably change it to a 8 or 9 character match:  `(0 ?)([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){8,9}`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you so much it is really good explanation. I am unable to vote up at this stage otherwise would have voted up your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^0 ?[1-8] ?(?:[0-9] ?){8,9}$
```

I used anchors `^` and `$` to ensure that there is no leading or trailing digits.